# I want to Perform particular event only once

Tags: livecode

I have a button and it performs a particular task. I want to perform the particular task only once during the second mouse click I don't want to perform a particular task. Now, after the task I am simply disable the button is it any alternative method for the above mentioned problem. I am using the following code

```
global e
on mouseUp 
   replace "\$" with "{\XXdollarXX}" in field "MytextField" 
   put the text of field "MytextField" into ss 
   put "" into yy 
   put 0 into tmp 
   repeat with i = 1 to the number of chars in ss 
      if char i of ss contains "$" then 
         add 1 to tmp 
         if tmp = 1 then 
            put CR & char i of ss after yy 
         else 
            put char i of ss && CR after yy 
            put 0 into tmp 
         end if 
      else 
         put char i of ss after yy 
      end if 
   end repeat 
   put yy into the field "MytextField"
   disable me
end mouseUp
```

Comment: Why did you accept Richmond's answer as the solution to your problem? For this, I will downvote your question.

Comment: Thanks for changing the accept. I've upvoted it now (after making a tiny edit, to unlock my vote).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your problem is the duration of your script. If a script needs a lot of time to run, a user may click a second time, thinking that nothing happened. Normally, this would execute the script twice. You can prevent this using `wait with messages` and a locally declared variable.

```
local lBusy
on mouseUp
     // first provide a way to force-unlock the script
     if the shiftKey is down then put false into lBusy
     if lBusy is true then
          // warn that the script is running
          beep
          answer error "Please wait for the script to finish."
     else
          // lock the script
          put true into lBusy
          repeat with x = 1 to 100000
               // just do something that takes a lot of time
               add 1 to mySampleVar
               put "The current value is" && mySampleVar // msg box
               // make the loop non-blocking
               wait 0 millisecs with messages
          end repeat
          // unlock the script
          put false into lBusy
     end if
end mouseUp
```

When the script starts, `lBusy` is set to `true`. At the end of the script, `lBusy` is set to `false` again. As long as `lBusy` is `true`, the script won't run if you click on the button.

Answer (score 0):

If your buttons all start their actions using a "mouseUp" message, group them and place that handler in the group script. Then you can distinguish the target button and run the appropriate code, pertinent to each button. But since all action is in a single handler, you can lock out any such message from any of the siblings in that group.